# Python piramiko, Connection Timed Out Error While Establishing SSH Connection

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am working on a project in **Python** that will create an **Amazon ec2 instance**, and establish a **SSH and SFTP connection** to transfer files and commands between my machine and ec2 instance.

So I began to code, *I coded the function that creates an ec2 instance using boto3 library.*

```
# creating a file named sefa.pem that will store the private key
outfile = open('sefa.pem', 'w')
keypair = ec2.meta.client.create_key_pair(KeyName='sefakeypair')  # creates key pair
keyout= str(keypair['KeyMaterial'])  # reads the key material
outfile.write(keyout)  # writes the key material in sefa.pem

# creates the instance finally
response = ec2.create_instances(ImageId='ami-34913254', MinCount=1, MaxCount=1, InstanceType='t2.micro')
```

After that, I should establish a SSH Connection between my machine and ec2 instance to send command and I also should transfer and bring back files between my machine and ec2 instance.

After research, I found out that there is a Python library called **piramiko** for establishing *SSH Connection and SFTP Connection* between my computer and ec2 instance.

I tried to establish a SSH Connection between my computer and ec2 instance, but I have been  facing with the **"[Errrno 110]Connection Timed Out Error"** for a day. I have been searching the internet for hours, but I couldn't find anything useful.
Here is the code that emerges "Connection Time Out Error":

```
    con = paramiko.SSHClient()  # ssh client using paramiko library
    con.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())  # this is needed because of adding policy automautically
    k = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("sefa.pem")  # k reads sefa.pem and stores private key
    time.sleep(30)  # added this because ec2 should do 2/2 checks  before connecting
    print("connecting")
    con.connect(hostname=PUB_DNS, username="ubuntu", pkey=k, look_for_keys=True)  # HERE IS THE ERROR, I CAN'T CONNECT
    print("connected")
    stdin, stdout, stderr = con.exec_command('echo "TEST"')
    print(stdout.readlines())
    con.close()
```

*I can not go any further without establishing a connection between my machine and ec2 instance.*

- **Do you have any suggestions to solve this problem?**
- **Is there any alternative library to piramiko?**

Comment: At first glance, I have two thoughts. One is that your `time.sleep()` might be the culprit, causing the ssh session to timeout as it appears to block the connection and the server you're trying to connect to might drop the connection by that point. The other thought is: have you tried running the commands *manually* and do they succeed? Your ``connect()`` call might be invalid.

Comment: I used `time.sleep()` because ssh connection needs to wait until ec2 instance's state is running and 2/2 checked. And I also **cannot** connect to ec2 instance manually, ssh gives the same connection timed out error.

Comment: Isn't there a better way to detect that? Why not attempt to connect without sleep, if it fails to connect, then sleep for a duration. Retry connection x seconds later and repeat until a successful connection is done. 30 seconds seems rather arbitrary.

Comment: The problem here is I can not connect to ec2 instance, and that is not because of the sleep, because when I tried to connect to the instance using `ssh -i /filepath/sefa.pem ubuntu@public_dns` and it emerged the same connection timed out error. Of course there are more convinent ways other than sleep, but I will cover that after I establish the ssh connection.

Comment: If you're getting the error using the basic shell command to connect, it's not the fault of the paramiko library. I'm not familiar with ec2, so I would suggest going through Amazon's support to find out why the connection is timing out. One last possibility: is the ssh daemon running on the ec2 instance?

Comment: How can I know whether the ssh is running on the ec2 or not? Can you explain, I should check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. The problem is my ec2 instance. These solved the issue:

- Make sure that instance's security group has ssh deamon and allows you to connect.
- Make sure that you have the keypair that you created while creating the instance.
- Make sure that you execute `chmod 400 keypair.pem`

Comment: Glad to hear that you figured it out! +1 for debugging skills

Comment: In my case i have pem file and i am able to so ssh from terminal but not using paramiko , any idea who is the culprit?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error and here is how I solved it :-

1. Install **openssh-client** on your client VM and **openssh-server** on your server VM.
2. Don't execute **ssh@ip address** as this will log you in to your host vm and then IP on both your client and server will be the same, this is the main reason for the error.

3.Instead use

ssh-keyscan *ip_address* >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

So know host key is in known hosts and original IP remains.